# Reload iframe src / location with new url not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I have a page that loads with initially just a form within an iframe, something like this:

`<iframe id="oIframe" ...src='somePage>'
  <form ... />
</iframe>`

When you click a button in the form, some javascript is invoked that builds a url and then I want to do the following:

`frame.src = 'somePage?listId=1';`

This works in IE to "reload" the frame with the new contents.
However, in Safari this does not work.

I have jQuery available, but I don't want to replace the existing iframe because there are events attached to it.  I also can not modify the id of the iframe because it is referenced throughout the application.

I have seen some similar issues but no solutions that seem to work well for my exact issue.

Any assistance anyone can provide would be great!

Comment: Are the frame URLs in the same domain as your outer (main) page?

Comment: yes the frame URLs are in the same domain as the main page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better solution (albeit not paticularly eloquent) for this using jQuery.ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "/somePage?someparms",
   success: function() {
      frameObj.src = "/somePage?someparms";
   }
});
```

This forces the DOM to be read within the frame object, and reloads it once the server is ready to respond.

Answer (score 8):

Some browsers don't use "src" when calling the javascript object directly from the javascript hierarchy and others use "location" or "href" instead of "src" to change the url . You should try these two methods to update your iframe with a new url.

To prevent browser cache add a pseudo-random string like a number and timestamp to the url to prevent caching. For example add "new Date().getTime()" to your url.

Some calling examples:

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).src = url;
```

or

```
window.frames[iframeName].location = url;
```

I recommend the first option using document.getElementById

Also you can force the iframe to reload a page using

```
document.getElementById(iframeId).reload(true);
```

Comment: i tried both and the src attribute is updated, but then when the frame loads it is still the original content.

Comment: I'm voting this up one for the as it helped in one aspect

Answer (score 5):

So the answer is very simple:
1. put a `<div id="container"> </div>` on your page
2. when reload needed use following jQuery:

```
$("#container").empty();
$("#container").append("<iframe src='" + url + "' />");
```

and that's it.
Of course there is more elegant way of creating DOM with jQuery but this gives the idea of "refreshing" iframe.
Works in FF18, CH24, IE9, O12 (well it's jQuery so it will work almost always :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
form.setAttribute('src', 'somePage?listId=1');
```

Comment: It should not be necessary to use "setAttribute()" to update the "src" property of a frame element, and in fact it may not work in some browsers.

Comment: There are several ways to modify a attribute - setAttribute is one of those. My idea behind the post is, that safari maybe does not support the notation frame.src = 'new uri here';

Comment: i had tried this and it did not work... i've seen something about safari caching iframe.  the src attribute actually gets updated but the request that is sent ( i am using fiddler to monitor ) is not the updated src url, rather whatever was first loaded into the frame

Comment: You can test the cache by trying to do: form.src = 'somePage?listId=1&random=552435'

The browser should cache by url, try to modify the url to see if it is working

Comment: so the frame.src should just reload the target frame.  there are 3 other frames that should not get reloaded.

Comment: I'm upvoting this for the comment about testing the cache - I was able to prove that the browser is caching the URL using this technique

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to find what appears to be a feasible solution -- it's a work in progress, but this is basically what I ended up doing:

```
var myFrame = document.getElementById('frame'); // get frame  
myFrame.src = url; // set src attribute of original frame  
var originalId = myFrame.id; // retain the original id of the frame  
var newFrameId = myFrame.id + new Date().getTime(); // create a new id  
var newFrame = "<iframe id=\"" + newFrameId + "\"/>"; // iframe string w/ new id  
myFrameParent = myFrame.parentElement; // find parent of original iframe  
myFrameParent.innerHTML = newFrame; // update innerHTML of parent  
document.getElementById(newFrameId).id = originalId; // change id back
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue using React, passing the `key` as `props.src` solved it

```
const KeyedIframe = ({children, ...props}) => <iframe key={props.src} { ...props}>
  {children}
</iframe>
```